# My App Installs Two Applications - Android

Tags: android, manifest, program-entry-point, launcher

Whenever I try to run my App, it installs two app in the emulator/device. I only want to Install my Main Activity, but the Splash Activity installs also. I know the problem is in the Manifest. Can anyone help me please? Here is my code:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.android.upcurrents.launcher.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.android.upcurrents.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have only one activity to be declared as the launcher. So, remove the intent-filter from within the SplashActivity's tag, and add it to your MainActivity. The Launcher intent-filter should be present in only one of the activities in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

It installs based on the intent filter you have provided.
Remove the following intent filter from SplashActivity and then put it in Main Activity

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.android.upcurrents.launcher.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>

<activity
android:name="com.android.upcurrents.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but I fixed it with the making sure you only have one activity with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In my code I had two activities with that intent-filter, which caused two applications to be installed on my device.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem but i fixed it this way
before my code  below in manifest

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity        android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.noupdate.apptest_noupdate.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Notice that in the SplashActivity inside the intent is this code

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

i only deleted the category

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

So after i deleted the intent-filter category in splash it didn't install two app icon but only one for main the code will be like this  notice that the intent-filter category is deleted

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity     android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.noupdate.apptest_noupdate.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

it really helps